# Switching image source with class not working,

Tags: javascript, css, web

I'm trying to make an image switch to another one by changing it's source path, and at the same time add a css class into it each time it switches. However I cant figure out the right way to do it for hours now. I'm just new to javascript.

This is what I have tried so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
                <div class="animBox">
                    <img src="images/astroboy2.png" class="astroboy2">
                    <img id="iconsID" src="images/Pencil.png" class="icons"> // this is the image I'm working on.
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .icons {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    right: 23%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

JS: (I have made an arrays for the path referrence of the images)

```
let IMG = {
    imageToswitch: document.getElementById("iconsID");
    imagePath: ["images/Ps_Logo.png", "images/Pencil.png", "images/joystick.png"],
    indexPos: 0,

    switching: () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        if (IMGS.indexPos == 2) {
            IMGS.indexPos = 0;
        }
        IMGS.icons.classList.add("icons");
        IMGS.icons.src = IMGS.imagePath[IMGS.indexPos];
        IMGS.indexPos++;
        IMGS.icons.classList.remove("icons");
    }, 900);
}
}
```

the only thing that is working here is the switching of the image source, but the css class is not working, that makes the images not on the right position and sizes.

Comment: you are adding the class then remove it

Comment: I know sir, my goal is how to do the right way to switch image along with its css class

Comment: Why did you add the `icons` class, then remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you just make 3 seperate classes to match each source, then handle it this way?

```
sources = ["src1","src2","src3"];
classes = ["class1","class2","class3"]
x = document.getElementById("eleID");
count = 0;
setInterval(function() {
x.src = sources[count];
x.className = classes[count];
if(count++==2){count=0}
},900)
```